# import error cant find module ast when i start VIM editor wit pyflakes

Tags: python, vim, osx-lion, python-2.7, pyflakes

On my Macbook (OSX Lion) I'm running python 2.7 with Vim 7.3 and installed pyflakes.

I followed the steps [described here](https://github.com/yodiaditya/vim-pydjango/blob/master/README.md), but installed pyflakes, pylint and pep8 with macports.

After running `Bundleinstall` and starting new Vim I got the following errormessage:

```
Import Error: cant find module ast
```

Comment: for the voters, this is [**most definitely** not off-topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-do-they-belong-to-stack-overflow-or-super-user). It is about programming in Python, extending Vim

Answer (score 0):

Because of a bug in versions of vim < 7.3.430, vundle may not like `filetype on` during configuration. However, pyflakes needs `filetype on`

If you cannot update vim to escape the bug, then a workaround is to flip on the filetype
before vundle configures pyflakes and then back off afterwards.
For example

```
filetype on
Bundle 'kevinw/pyflakes-vim'
filetype off
```